# Error loading EFI module from EFI System Partition

Tags: boot, uefi, efi, fat32

I've create ESP image as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=esp.img count=$((0x60000)) bs=1
mkfs.fat esp.img
mount esp.img /mnt
mkdir -p /mnt/EFI/BOOT
cp bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/BOOT
```

I've copied the image to the drive (dd) to the offset where the old esp was located (with the same size) (so the mbr is pointing to EFI System Partition in the same offset)

There is error booting from it,
When I use EFI Shell to try to boot from it

`FS2:> load bootx64.efi
Image 'bootx64.efi' is not an image.`

also i cannot read a txt file that is located in there:

`Shell> type test.txt
type: Operation was not successful on 'test.txt'`

It seems like the UEFI cannot read the fat32 partition although i can read mount and read it with `mount esp.img /mnt`

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you properly unmount the image before dd'ing to the destination? Are you able to mount the actual partition?

Comment: The partition can be mounted within EFI Shell, I can list files.

Comment: At the `FS2:>` prompt, try `bootx64.efi` instead of `load bootx64.efi`.  At the `FS2:>`, try `type test.txt`